# Only one dynamic data object loading into a component at a time vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, components, dynamic-content

I've been struggling to learn Vue for a little while now, and am still having trouble wrapping my head around its data-oriented model, and particularly the syntax for using that data. I've successfully called data from the cloud, but can only seem to render one piece of it at a time into a Vuetify stepper. If the number of steps is rendered, the associated content is not, and vice versa.

From my :

```
<v-stepper v-model="e1">
      <v-stepper-header>
        <template v-for="n in steps">
          <v-stepper-step
            :complete="e1 > n"
            :key="`${n}-step`"
            :step="n"
          >
            Step {{ n }}
          </v-stepper-step>

          <v-divider
            v-if="n !== steps"
            :key="n"
          ></v-divider>
        </template>
      </v-stepper-header>

      <v-stepper-items>
        <v-stepper-content
          v-for="n in steps"
          :key="`${n}-content`"
          :step="n"
        >
          <v-card
            class="mb-5"
            color="grey lighten-1"
            height="200px"          
            >{{content[e1-1].city}} {{content[e1-1].name}}</v-card>


          <v-btn
            color="#5BB0FF"
            @click="nextStep(n)"
          >
            Continue
          </v-btn>

          <v-btn flat>Cancel</v-btn>
        </v-stepper-content>
      </v-stepper-items>
    </v-stepper>
```

From my `<script>`:

```
import JQuery from 'jquery'
let $ = JQuery

export default {
  name: 'ProgressSteps',
  data () {
      return {
        e1: 1,
        steps: 3,
        content: [
      ]
      }
    },
    watch: {
      steps (val) {
        if (this.e1 > val) {
          this.e1 = val
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      nextStep (n) {
        if (n === this.steps) {
          this.e1 = 1
        } else {
          this.e1 = n + 1
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
    $.post("https://fleetr-208415.appspot.com/get-current-dropoff-locations.php")
    .done(response => {this.content = JSON.parse(response);
        this.steps = JSON.parse(response).length
    })
},
}
```

Here's a codepen that demonstrates this behavior. If you replace `steps: 3` with `steps: ''`, the content disappears, even though it renders the three steps, as expected. https://codepen.io/redheadedmandy/pen/WyWQBe?editors=1010

Comment: But why you want to replace it with `""` ?

Comment: ... I swear, every question I post on here ends with me saying "I'm an idiot." I wanted to leave it unset initially, thus the " ", but apparently I just had to give it some value, which would then be changed by the mounted() function.

Comment: Do you want' to hide the stepper initially? or what?

Comment: Or can't you set `e1: 0` rather than setting steps to `''`?

Comment: No, I just want the stepper to be rendered from the data being passed to it; I didn't realize that any initial value for "steps" was going to be overwritten once I set it in the mounted() function, not just a null value. So `steps=2` still renders three steps, along with their content.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in the `script` Hope this is what you are looking for.

1. Kept `steps: 1,` as it is mandatory to initialize the script.
2. I have hardcoded the value to `2` in the `step` in your `mounted()` function but it is working with dynamically rendered data.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGLNLE?editors=1010

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote it up if it helped?